# Compiling glib2 from the scratch

Tags: c, glib

i want to compile glib2 for a specific platform. It needs gettext, so I passed where the gettext libraries are. For example:

```
    $ ./configure CC=.. CFLAGS=... -prefix=.. LDFLAGS="-L../libconv/lib/ -L../gettext/usr/local/lib" --enable-shared=no
```

but it returns:

```
    ....
    checking libintl.h usability... no
    checking libintl.h presence... no
    checking for libintl.h... no
    configure: error: 
    *** You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or use the
    *** GNU gettext library. (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html
```

Do you have any idea about why it doesn't detect gettext?

Thanks.

Comment: You might get answer from [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/338656/installing-glib-gives-you-must-have-either-have-gettext-support),[this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/14109) or [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-from-scratch-13/no-gettext-support-in-c-library-147703/)

Answer (score 0):

While "installing" everything in a directory under your home directory, you needed to add the "bin" subdirectory of the --prefix directory to your $PATH before running configure.

Answer (score 0):

download the latest package from here:
http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/
compile it and run your configure command again and it should fix the issue.